# Not being asked to interview a new hire

Tags: management, communication, hiring-process

My company has recently made a new hire for a position within my team. My team currently consists of entirely non-technical members including my manager with the exception of myself.

The position being hired for is of a technical nature and as such, I would be working with the new hire the most out of all my coworkers. I have been informed by the other interviewers (who are all from non-technical backgrounds and some of which are members of my team) that the interviews were primarily fit based.

I have not been asked to interview the candidate at all and thus do not know how the new hire will perform in the role. Furthermore, my manager has not mentioned anything in regards to the new hire and I've only been able to gather information from other interviewers.

I think the hiring process is unusual but I don't have much experience to go on. Does this process sound unusual? Should this be viewed as a red flag against my current employer and manager?

This question is similar to the question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/58988/48044).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you asked your manager directly about this? That should be your first port of call. Be direct and say you had concerns about how the technical knowledge of the new hire was tested in the interview so that you know what gaps exist in that persons expertise and can help bridge those gaps. The person was employed for good reasons

Generally, interviews are held with one HR representative, that persons line manager and if they are working with another manager closely, that person too. The interview that you describe is fine but could have been better by your manager talking to you first to help him understand what technical knowledge is required.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this process sound unusual?

Not for a low level tech job where fit is more important than tech skills. Which it seems this would be. When hiring a junior engineer for instance, if they have the basic qualification, then that's all they really need to learn on the job.

For positions which require very advanced skills and experience it's another story.

In any case it's a management decision.